# Postfix: Make request on send

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to make a `GET` request to an external server when a mail is being sent, ideally, pass the sender's username to the request as well. I'm trying to keep it as light-weight as possible, and because only the sender username is needed, there's no need to wait for the email body. Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Is a `content_filter` the only way?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Mta always queue all mail and send it from queue so only from log you can say the mail is sent

Comment: All checks and filtering is for incoming mail only

Comment: @gapsf Can a hook be somehow added? The mail doesn't have to be sent. I'd be happy to capture when it's being sent.

Comment: https://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html

Comment: @gapsf Thanks. I'll check it out.